# Proving two lines in vector form intersect algebraically

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

let $x,y,a,b,c,d$ be vectors and $r,k \in \Bbb{R}$ with vector $d$ not being a scalar multiple of vector $b$ How would you prove that the line
$\vec{x}=\vec{a}+r\vec{b}$ intersects the line $\vec{y}=\vec{c}+k\vec{d}$ algebraically in $\Bbb{R^2}$?

Geometrically In $\Bbb{R^2}$ since $\vec{b}$ and $\vec{d}$ are not scalar multiples then they are not parallel and since they are in the x-y plane then obviously the two lines will not intersect, however i am having trouble expressing this algebraically

Comment: do you mean equations of the form $y=ax+b,y=cx+d$?

Comment: or $$\vec{x}=\vec{x_0}+t\vec{a}$$?

Comment: $\vec{x}=\vec{x_0}+t\vec{a}$

Answer (score 1):

By hypothesis, the vectors $\vec b$ and $\vec d$ are linearly independent, so they form a basis for $\mathbb R^2$: every vector can be written as a linear combination of them. In particular, there are scalars $\lambda, \mu\in\mathbb R$ such that $\vec a-\vec c = \mu\vec d-\lambda\vec b$, which is equivalent to $\vec a+\lambda\vec b=\vec c+\mu\vec d$.

Answer (score 0):

$a_x+rb_x=c_x+kd_x, \ a_y+rb_y=c_y+kd_y$, where x and y refer to the coordinate directions (not to the original vectors).  You now have two linear equations in two unknowns (r and k).  Solve.